# Recuperar uma flag em uma função

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql

Eu possuo uma função em um script php onde, nela, devo recuperar os valores 1 ou 3 de uma tabela no mysql (1 - documentos pertinentes a prestadores de serviços, 2 -documentos dos contratos (empresas) para o qual esses prestadores trabalharam)

O código abaixo provê uma "lupa" que, atualmente, me traz esses dois tipos de documentos misturados em uma lista:

```
<a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-xs btdoc btn-default" data-key="<?= $value['id_prestador'] ?>" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Visualizar/Anexar documentos">
```

abaixo, a função onde devo recuperar / implementar esse filtro ( no caso gerar uma "lupa" separada apenas para os documentos da empresa:

```
protected function getDocs() {


    global $prestador;

    try {

       $query = "SELECT ps.c_razao as prestador, A.prestador_tipo_doc_id, A.prestador_tipo_doc_nome, B.prestador_documento_id, 
                COUNT(B.prestador_documento_id) AS qnt 
                FROM prestador_tipo_doc AS A
                LEFT JOIN prestador_documentos AS B ON (A.prestador_tipo_doc_id = B.prestador_tipo_doc_id AND B.id_prestador = $prestador)
                JOIN prestadorservico as ps on ps.id_prestador = $prestador
                WHERE A.status = 1    
                GROUP BY A.prestador_tipo_doc_id
                ORDER BY A.ordem";

        $this->rh->Prestadorservico->setDefault()->setIdPrestador($prestador)->select("c_razao")->getRow();
        $this->nomePrestador = $this->rh->Prestadorservico->getCRazao();

        $exec = $this->db->setDefault()->setQuery(QUERY, $query)->execute();
        if (!$exec->isOk()){
            $this->error->set("Houve um erro na montagem da listagem dos DOCs", E_FRAMEWORK_ERROR);
        }

        $this->rsDocs = $exec->getArray();

         if (!include_once(ROOT_APP_TEMPLATE . 'admin/prestador/listar_docs.php')) die('Não foi possível incluir ' . ROOT_APP_TEMPLATE . 'admin/prestador/listar_docs.php');


    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        $this->setValue(0)->error->set(array(1, __METHOD__), E_FRAMEWORK_WARNING, $ex);
        echo $this->getAlertHtml($this->rh->getAllMsgCode(null, "<br/>"));
        // return $this;
        //echo $this->rh->error->getAllMsgCodeJson(array('code' => 0, 'status' => $this->isOk()));
    }

}
```

Eu tenho buscado entender, qual interação as tags html/javascript fazem com a função php acima, para ter uma idéia de como vou modificar isso. Foi esse o caminho que me apontaram aqui no escritório, mas tem sido difícil relacionar uma coisa com a outra. A maioria das perguntas e soluções que encontrei são bem genéricas.

Para tornar mais fácil o entendimento da questão, quando vou inspecionar no chrome ele me mostra claramente o método getDocs sendo invocado. Mas gostaria mesmo de entender, em que lugar das tags abaixo isso é passado:

```
<a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-xs btdoc btn-default" data-key="<?= $value['id_prestador'] ?>" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Visualizar/Anexar documentos">
```

**EDIT**: Ao debugar com o firefox, encontrei a referência na tag acima (btdoc) , no script abaixo:

```
$(document).on("click", ".btdoc", function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        var key = $this.data("key");
        /*var kids = $this.parents("tr").children();
        var razao = kids.next().next().html();*/
        cria_carregando_modal();

        $.post("?class=admin/prestador/gestao", {prestador: key, method: "getDocs"}, function (data) {
            remove_carregando_modal();
            bootDialog(data, 'Lista de Documentos', '', 'info');
        }, 'html');
    });
```

Basicamente o que fiz foi "replicar" (sim, entendo que isso foi uma gambiarra) o mesmo script, mas desta vez com uma referência `".btdoc_prestador"` , chamando um método semelhante ao qual dei o nome de `getDocs_prestador`:

```
protected function getDocs_prestador() {


    global $prestador;

    try {

        $query2 = "SELECT ps.c_razao as prestador, A.prestador_tipo_doc_id, A.prestador_tipo_doc_nome, B.prestador_documento_id, 
                COUNT(B.prestador_documento_id) AS qnt 
                FROM prestador_tipo_doc AS A
                LEFT JOIN prestador_documentos AS B ON (A.prestador_tipo_doc_id = B.prestador_tipo_doc_id AND B.id_prestador = $prestador)
                JOIN prestadorservico as ps on ps.id_prestador = $prestador
                WHERE  A.status = 1 AND A.tipo_doc = 2
                GROUP BY A.prestador_tipo_doc_id
                ORDER BY A.ordem";

        $this->rh->Prestadorservico->setDefault()->setIdPrestador($prestador)->select("c_razao")->getRow();
        $this->nomePrestador = $this->rh->Prestadorservico->getCRazao();

        $exec = $this->db->setDefault()->setQuery(QUERY, $query2)->execute();
        if (!$exec->isOk()){
            $this->error->set("Houve um erro na montagem da listagem dos DOCs", E_FRAMEWORK_ERROR);
        }
```

Ele está me retornando a listagem de documentos conforme a flag que coloquei na query : `A.tipo_doc = 2`

O problema agora é que a exibição dos modais com a listagem ficou super bugada, como na imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**EDIT 2**  Além do resultado que eu esperava, na verdade a página esta carregando vários modais no ato do mesmo click. Inclusive de tipos diferentes.

**EDIT 3** A renderização do modal ta demorando muito tbm:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: $query = "SELECT ps.c_razao as prestador, nessa parte do código não deveria "prestador" estar como uma váriavel?

Comment: Ou melhor, qual valor é retornado?

Comment: Olá, @PedroHenrique Na verdade, prestador configura apenas um alias para a tabela. Eu consegui implementar a chamada das diferentes listas de documentos conforme a dondição SQL nos métodos. Editei o tópico e adicionei uma imagem para melhor compreensão.